# CORS : Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Tags: cors, axios

When I executed this codes, I got `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

```
 axios({
     url: this.state.optImage[i],
     method: 'get',
     withCredentials: true,
     headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://*, http://*',
     }
 })
```

I requested to s3 server, and in postman, it worked well.
I also tried adding '*' in 'Access-Control-allow-Origin'.
What's wrong with my codes? Is does only happen in localhost? I don't understand at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass xsrf-token or something else in headers. It's hard to know just with that code. Try add some backend code..